# Item showing during debug otherwise not showing item in ListView

Tags: java, android

This is my code, when I debugging then code work properly means list item show in Listview but without debugging list item not showing in this code Listview empty

```
ImageView cancl1e = convertView1.findViewById(R.id.btncance);

if (jsonArray.length() > 0) {

    listView = convertView1.findViewById(R.id.Benificiarylist);
    adapter = new Recipient_ListAdapter(MoneyTransferFragment.this,value);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    cancl1e.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alertDialog1.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alertDialog1.setView(convertView1);
    alertDialog1.show();

} else {
    Nodatafound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly handle dialog separately. It's working while debugging because while debugging its getting time between display data dialog I guess. Please specify if wrong.